# How to clear persistent variables in sub-functions

Tags: matlab

I have a script that calls a function, which is written in separate file and contains sub-functions that are inner to main function only. In one of my sub-functions, I have persistent variable that I would like to clear every time I run the main script. How can I do so? In addition, I have breakpoints through my code, and I would prefer to keep them while I clear the persistent variable - how that can be done?

MainScript.m script:

```
clear variables;
for iterNum=1:5
   dataOut = MyMainFunction(iterNum);
end
disp(dataOut);
```

MyMainFunction code:

```
function dataOut = MyMainFunction(iterNum)
   if (iterNum==1)
      clear MySubFunction;
   end
   dataOut = MySubFunction();
end

function dataOut = MySubFunction()
   persistent idx;
   if isempty(idx)
      idx=1;
   end
   dataOut=idx;
   idx=idx+1;
end
```

I would like to clear "idx" persistent variable every time that I run MainScript.m, but of course to keep that variable as long as the script is running.

Thanks, John

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I see is to call `clear` followed the function name:

```
clear MySubFunction
```

instead of

```
clear variables;
```

This should clear all the persistent variables in that particular function. This will probably have the side effect of removing the stored JIT'd copy of it, causing it to be reparsed the next time it is invoked.

You can use [`munlock`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/munlock.html) if you previously [`mlock`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlock.html)'ed your function.

**OR**

You can define a special set of parameters in your function that are designed to solely clear the persistent variable, and you call the function with this syntax at the beginning of your main file.

Comment: I would use the second option - add an init flag to the argument list, under which persistent variables are cleared and the function then exits.

Comment: @Naveh:
Well, I already did as you suggested but there are two problems with those solutions:
1) I cannot call "Clear MySubFunction" in MainScript.m as it's not known by the script, but only MyMainFunction is known.
2) I tried to call "Clear MySubFunction" in MyMainFunction with some special init flag in the argument list as you suggested, but the problem is that it still doesn't work, and the persistent variable is still not reset.

Comment: @J.Smith, make your persistent `idx` as a variable of  `MyMainFunction`, and make `MySubFunction` as a [nested](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) function of `MyMainFunction`. This way `idx` will be shared between the 2 functions, and `idx` will be cleared when you call `clear MyMainFunction` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: @Hoki, I know I can use nested functions, but for readability and comfort I prefer using local functions. I usually try to avoid nested functions.

Comment: @JSmith Nested function are a great tool. They are as readable as subfunctions, you definitely should not deprive yourself from using all the features offered by the langage. Once you use it you realize how comfortable it can be. My advice: open your mind and  go !

Comment: This answer is wrong - you can't `clear` a subfunction from within the same m-file (nor from outside, but for different reasons) - see my own answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the other answer is partially incorrect - it is **NOT** possible to clear persistent variables in a sub-function using `clear MySubFunction`.

To quote [an answer by a MathWorks staff member](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/241417-clear-persistent-variables-in-sub-functions#answer_191810),

> Only top level or main functions (with the same name as the file) may be cleared. To clear any local or nested function the main function must be cleared and that can't be done while the main function (or any other function in the file) is running.

and

> Only whole m files can be cleared from memory. The entire file is managed as a unit so sub functions can't be cleared without clearing the main function.

As such, your options are to

- separate the sub-function into its own m-file, or
- clear the entire `MyMainFunction` from within `MainScript.m`, or
- follow Ratbert's second suggestion, i.e. instead of using `clear`, give `MySubFunction` an additional argument that tells it to reset the persistent variables by itself